# using ifelse statement but from dataset in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grepl

to create attributes, i can do so

```
dat$clas <- ifelse(grepl("den", dat$stuff), "bak", 
                  ifelse(grepl("kro", dat$stuff), "bak1", 

  ifelse(grepl("ris", dat$stuff), "bak3",  
         ifelse(grepl("muka", dat$stuff), "rty", 

               ifelse(grepl("chlo", dat$stuff), "cos", 
              ifelse(grepl("prokl", dat$stuff), "gig",  "no"))))))
```

but what i have many attributes, suppose  there are 200 attributes.
Using  such ifelse statement is a long time to write and there will be a long code.
Can  i use it from dataframe.

```
templatedata<-prod  clas
den               bak
kro              bak1
ris               bak3
muka            rty
chlo               cos
prokl                gig
```

)

```
templatedata=structure(list(prod = structure(c(2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("chlo\t", 
"den", "kro\t", "muka", "prokl\t", "ris\t"), class = "factor"), 
    class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("bak", 
    "bak1", "bak3", "cos", "gig", "rty"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("prod", 
"class"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

so

```
workingdataset<-(
prod
den sg
kro serdgt
ris szdg
muka aszgt
chlo sdgt
prokl zfdsgr
den zdasfh)


workingdataset=structure(list(prod = structure(c(2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("chlo sdgt", 
"den sg", "den zdasfh)", "kro serdgt", "muka aszgt", "prokl zfdsgr", 
"ris szdg"), class = "factor")), .Names = "prod", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

i use templatedata to get attribute in workigdataset.

as output `workingdataset` looks like

```
prod           clas
den   sg        bak
kro  serdgt      bak1
ris szdg        bak3
muka aszgt      rty
chlo sdgt       cos
prokl   zfdsgr  gig
den  vv         bak
```

how to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right it is not for my task (i work with phrases)

Comment: @MrFlick, i edited post, all can i do , it is do dput . Now workingdataset contain phrases with key words. i must create attributes from templatedata by this keyword

Comment: @MrFlick, i provided dput

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the wonderful [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package created by David Robinson. It allows you to join two tables using fuzzy logic, including string distances or regular expressions. Here, we'll use regular expressions.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(magrittr)

workingdataset=structure(list(prod = structure(c(2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L), 
                                               .Label = c("chlo sdgt", 
                                                          "den sg", 
                                                          "den zdasfh)", 
                                                          "kro serdgt", 
                                                          "muka aszgt", 
                                                          "prokl zfdsgr", 
                                                          "ris szdg"), 
                                               class = "factor")), 
                         .Names = "prod", 
                         class = "data.frame", 
                         row.names = c(NA, -7L))

templatedata=structure(list(prod = structure(c(2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L), 
                                             .Label = c("chlo", 
                                                        "den", 
                                                        "kro", 
                                                        "muka", 
                                                        "prokl", 
                                                        "ris"), 
                                             class = "factor"), 
                            class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), 
                                              .Label = c("bak", "bak1", "bak3", 
                                                         "cos", "gig", "rty"), 
                                              class = "factor")), 
                       .Names = c("prod", "class"), 
                       class = "data.frame", 
                       row.names = c(NA, -6L))

workingdataset %>%
    regex_inner_join(templatedata, by='prod')

        prod.x prod.y class
1       den sg    den   bak
2   kro serdgt    kro  bak1
3     ris szdg    ris  bak3
4   muka aszgt   muka   rty
5    chlo sdgt   chlo   cos
6 prokl zfdsgr  prokl   gig
7  den zdasfh)    den   bak
```